# Build a RESTful POST API in ObjectScript

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

how to build a RESTful POST API in ObjectScript whereas schema is like this. It should accept myList conforming to the schema.

```
 {
    "$schema": "link",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
       "myList": {
          "type": "array",
          "items":{
             "type": "string"
          }
       }
    },
    "required": [
       "myList"
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Creating REST Services](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GREST_services) chapter in documentation. It describes the process.

Answer (score 1):

See also REST in InterSystems Caché articles [here](https://community.intersystems.com/tags/rest-services)